# Python количество значение символов в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть список с помощью len посчитал количество элементов в списке получил ответ 5 теперь мне нужно посчитать каждый из значений, как мне это сделать помогите пожалуйста я Python новичок)
ответ должно быть таким

ба = 2

ман = 3

пиёда =5

....

```
st="ман ба мактаб меравам пиёда"
arr=st.split()
print(len(arr))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примените `len` к каждому элементу списка. Проще всего это сделать с помощью спискового включения:

```
print(*[f'{s} = {len(s)}\n' for s in arr])

 ман = 3
 ба = 2
 мактаб = 6
 меравам = 7
 пиёда = 5
```

Ну или может более понятный вам будет вариант с обычным циклом `for`:

```
for s in arr:
    print(f'{s} = {len(s)}')
```

P.S. Отметил ещё чётные цифры надписью по просьбе автора вопроса:

```
print(*[f'{s} = {len(s)} {"четное" if len(s) % 2 == 0 else ""}\n' for s in arr])
```

Вывод:

```
 ман = 3 
 ба = 2 четное
 мактаб = 6 четное
 меравам = 7 
 пиёда = 5
```

Comment: CrazyElf, а можно ли в этот код добавить еще и показала четные цифры? print(*[f'{s} = {len(s)}\n' for s in arr])

Comment: @ariana Добавил код, если я вас правильно понял